# Context API with more hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-context

I have a question related to API and react hooks.
I would like to dispatch the API fetch to ContextAPI component.
Is there a possible way to put all useState hooks:

```
    const [tab, setTab] = useState([]); 
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(''); 
    const [query, setQuery] = useState(''); 
    const [select, setSelect] = useState([]);
```

To a single ContextAPI component ?? The main goal is to refactor code and put into small components. For example **Form component**, **Input component**, **Select component**

```
const App = () => {
    const [tab, setTab] = useState([]); 
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(''); 
    const [query, setQuery] = useState(''); 
    const [select, setSelect] = useState([]); 


    useEffect(() => {
        getTabulatura();
    }, [query]);


    const getTabulatura = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://www.songsterr.com/a/ra/songs.json?pattern=${query}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setTab(newData);
    }

    const updateSearch = e => {
        setSearch(e.target.value);
    }

    const getSearch = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setQuery(search);
    }

    const tabChange = e => {
        const filteredData = tab.filter(tabItem => tabItem.tabTypes.some(type => type === e.target.value))
        setSelect(filteredData)
    }



    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="container">
                <h1 className="header-title">Find the music type of tablature !</h1>
                <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="search-form" >
                    <input className="search-bar" placeholder="Write artist/song" value={search} onChange={updateSearch} />
                    <select className="select-tab" onChange={tabChange} >
                        <option value="none" > --Choose tab-- </option>
                        <option value="chords" > chords </option>
                        <option value="bass" > bass </option>
                        <option value="guitar" > guitar </option>
                        <option value="player" > player </option> </select>
                    <button className="search-button" type='submit' >Search </button>
                </form>
                <div className="tabulatury" > {
                    select.map(tabType => (<Tabulatura
                        title={tabType.title}
                        artist={tabType.artist.name}
                        tabulatura={tabType.tabTypes}
                        key={tabType.id}
                    />
                    ))};
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for formik form library?
Try fromik which is very popular form library for react js & react native.
You can build custom form components with the help of Formik.

https://formik.org/docs/overview

Here are the some lines from documentation
Formik is a small library that helps you with the 3 most annoying parts:
1.Getting values in and out of form state
2.Validation and error messages
3.Handling form submission

By colocating all of the above in one place, Formik will keep things organized--making testing, refactoring, and reasoning about your forms a breeze